# How we calculate critical point in mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

Can be calculated critical point in Mathematica if we have three simultaneous equation.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here its considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If  you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) it will inspire great answers.

Comment: The term "critical point" appears in many different contents. You need to explain what type of the critical point you have in mind, and give equations you are thinking about in the form of a Mathematica code.